# How to make Css go along Image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a problem with `CSS` and `bootstrap`. When I test my layout, happens a smash[image]

My code:

```css
.imgNotspace img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.imgNotspace h3 {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #F38630;
  color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<section class="pgPrincipal container">
  <article class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 imgNotspace">
      <h3 class="col-sm-12">teste</h3>
      <img src="~/Uploads/Imagens/teste.jpg" class="col-md-12  img-responsive" />
      <footer>
        <h3 class="col-md-12">TestTes</h3>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

I want than the `<h3>` stay the image.
How I can to make that?

Comment: What do you mean by _I want than the `<h3>` stay the image_? What is your expected output?

Comment: @JohnBupit I Want than a Box  what is with orange color, stay with same width than a image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's [Thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

```css
h3 {
  background: #F38630;
  color: #FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <h3>Thumbnail heading</h3>

        <img src="https://placehold.it/250x200">

        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail caption</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```